# Dashcam parking mode settings for hybrid?

Tags: electrical, hybrid, dashcam

I am installing a Thinkware F800 dashcam in a 2017 Toyota Highlander Hybrid.

To enable recording while parked, the camera has two power inputs, one that should be ignition-switched and one that should be always on. While in parking mode, the camera monitors the voltage it is receiving and shuts down if the voltage drops too low in order to prevent fully draining the vehicle's battery. Because different vehicles are different, it allows setting what that cutoff voltage should be.

Does this voltage setting matter for a hybrid, given that it has no starter motor? I assume that this power is coming from the auxiliary 12v battery, not the main traction battery. Is there anything else that can go wrong if I let the 12v battery get low - I assume the only things that matter are the power door locks, ignition power button, and radio presets, but those should all still be fine at lower voltage.